# (Python) gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox, socket


root = Tk()
root.title("pynet v1.0")
root.config(bg='black')
root.resizable(0,0)   

text = Text()   
text1 = Text()

text1.config(width=15, height=1)
text1.config(bg="white", fg="red")
text1.pack()

def Info():
    targetip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(text1.get("1.0", END))
    text.insert(END, targetip)

b = Button(root, text="Enter", width=10, height=2, command=Info)
b.config(fg="black", bg="red")
b.pack(side=TOP, padx=5)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.config(width=25, height=5, bg="white", fg="red")
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to retrieve the IP Address of a website, but I keep getting this error, "gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed" in line 18, your help will be appreciated, Thanks.

The Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Rabia\Desktop\gethostinfo.py", line 18, in Info
    targetip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(text1.get("1.0", END))
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: So that no one else has to count it out, line 19 is `targetip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(text1.get("1.0", END) + "\r\n")`

Comment: You have to get rid of the first wild import `from socket import *`. It does nothing except hurt performance and mess up the namespace. That probably won't solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is because you are using a hostname that has a trailing newline. At the time I write this answer, your code shows:

```
def Info():
    targetip = socket.gethostbyname_ex(text1.get("1.0", END))
    text.insert(END, targetip)
```

When you use the index `END` you get the extra newline that is added by the text widget. You need to strip that off or use the index `"end-1c"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding CRLF (`\r\n`) to the hostname before looking it up?

If removing that doesn't fix it, print out the exact text you're passing to gethostbyname to make sure it's a valid hostname.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to delete the (\r\n) sorry about that. I'm just typing in random websites, like msn.com, google.com, and nothing works.

Comment: Also, by using the index END you're getting a newline as the host name