# IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, urllib, ioerror, getaddrinfo

I am beginner python prorammer. With 2.7.2, Windows 7, built-in interpreter, and three libraries. I am trying to do this, with error. I appreciate any help?

```
import os
import urllib
import socket

DISNEY_URL = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001039/000119312511321340/dis-20111001.xml'
#Neither of these seem to work when opening with urllib.urlopen becaue of the error:
#I/O error(socket error): [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

DISNEY_LOCAL = 'file://C:/Users/Nate/Desktop/Education/python_education/xbrlnexusfiles/xbrlfiles/dis-20111001.xml'
DISNEY_LOCAL_NONE = 'file://C:/Users/Nate/Desktop/Education/python_education/xbrlnexusfiles/xbrlfiles/dis.txt'


class SECFilingPackage(object):

    def __init__ (self, SEC_URL):
        URLFilePath, URLFileExt = os.path.splitext(SEC_URL)
        try:
            urllib.urlopen(SEC_URL)
        except IOError as (errno, strerror):
            print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
            #This error throws, see it copied above;

DisneyPackage = SECFilingPackage(DISNEY_LOCAL_NONE)
```

I get this error:
I/O error(socket error):

> [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Yes the text file exists at that location. The contents of the text file is "Nothing"

The stack trace says the last call was line 516 in `open_ftp` `C:/Python27/Lib/urllib.py`:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname(host)
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I could open URLs fine, so I don't think it's a [proxy/firewall issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847649/opening-websites-using-urllib2-from-behind-corporate-firewall-11004-getaddrinf) (nor do I understand that really)

And I don't understand what [newlines or ENDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126023/python-gaierror-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed) might have to do with it.

I believe it should work because of the [urllib reference:](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)

> If the URL does not have a scheme identifier, or if it has file: as
>   its scheme identifier, this opens a local file (without universal
>   newlines); otherwise it opens a socket to a server somewhere on the
>   network.

(I think this just means someone who expects universal newlines already converted there, would be disappointed.

Note I also dispute the part about "if it does not have a scheme identifier", because if I don't precede the strings with `file://` I get

> IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: 'c')

I want to "learn to fish" so to speak, can anyone tell me is there a way I could debug into the `urllib.py` to at least understand these values? Can I do it with eclipse? It always seems to force me into a project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022945/urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `file://<filename>`, use `file:///<filename` (note the extra slash).

Also, please note that `urllib.urlopen` has been deprecated, you should use `urllib2.urlopen` instead.

Comment: He should actually use python-requests

Comment: Thank you, jcollado. And thanks, Antonioo. Python-requests does look nice... http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html